# Why leveldb uses two PutFixed32 to Encoding footer instead of one PutFixed64?

Tags: encoding, leveldb

Why does leveldb use two PutFixed32 instead of PutFixed64 directly in the process of encoding the magic number in the footer?

```
void Footer::EncodeTo(std::string* dst) const {
  const size_t original_size = dst->size();
  metaindex_handle_.EncodeTo(dst);
  index_handle_.EncodeTo(dst);
  dst->resize(2 * BlockHandle::kMaxEncodedLength);  // Padding
  PutFixed32(dst, static_cast<uint32_t>(kTableMagicNumber & 0xffffffffu));
  PutFixed32(dst, static_cast<uint32_t>(kTableMagicNumber >> 32));
...
}
```

It can be:

```
void Footer::EncodeTo(std::string* dst) const {
  const size_t original_size = dst->size();
  metaindex_handle_.EncodeTo(dst);
  index_handle_.EncodeTo(dst);
  dst->resize(2 * BlockHandle::kMaxEncodedLength);  // Padding
  PutFixed64(dst, kTableMagicNumber);
...
}
```

This way is more concise.

It's possible that using two PutFixed32 is faster than using one PutFixed64?